# Set a breakpoint for all search results in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I have made a search in PyCharm with classical <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and I just want to set a breakpoint at every line in result for debugging at once.

Does exists some functionality in the IDE to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such feature, unfortunately. Though you can place breakpoints manually in "Find in Path" preview window for a given search item.

Feel free to create a feature request in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY